# How to extract url from any string php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue  with want to extract URL from given string :

for example:

Lorum ipsum dolor is containg  http://www.mysiteurl.com
 and some time lorum ipsum dolor is containg: http://mysiteurl2.com
so on .. many times this type of URL may be in my WordPress editor,

so how I can extract those URLs septetrly  which one belong to with this text string lorum ipsum dolor

Please help

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract the url from an anchor tag that has been placed on a wordpress page?

Comment: Yes exactly you is the very closed to issue .   anchor tag that have been placed with a specific string  matches . for example  :-  Prem  from  india  with anchor link http://www.anyurls.com  string will be same but its annshror url will be different in post and pages editor.

Comment: Then it looks like @KerryKobashi has already provided a useful answer

Comment: Thanks but still not able to get my result. @RiggsFolly

Comment: thanks @kerry for the answer .

Comment: If you are waiting for someone to write you a WordPress plugin to do it all for you, you may have a long wait

Answer (score 0):

Use the Document Object Model class.

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML - loads HTML from a string
DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile - loads HTML from file
DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName - lets your filter by tag
```

Something like:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("hello.html");
$anchorTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach ($anchorTags as $anchorTag) {
  echo "Value: " . $anchorTag->nodeValue . "\n";
  echo "Href: " . $anchorTag->getAttribute("href") . "\n\n";
}
```